# Sorting by capital letters first

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Currently in my query I am saying `orderby t.Description` and I get:

```
1st street
2 burritos
Allergy
Ameripath
Application
APK THD
```

How can I change the sort to get this:

```
1st street
2 burritos
APK THD
Allergy
Ameripath
Application
```

So now it is still by description but the ones with capital letters come first

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328737/linq-and-case-sensitivity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to pass a ordinal comparer to OrderBy method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new[] {"1st street","2 burritos","Allergy","Ameripath","Application","APK THD"};
    list.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that would do it, except one issue: Before I return my query result, I am adding a one off item called "Show All" to the top of the list, but I don't want this one to get sorted, I want this one to still stay on top, How can I do that? Currently it sorts it like the rest of them.

Comment: You have to add it after sorting the list. You can use list.Insert(0, "ShowAll").